# Print out key values of array from form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, key

Currently I am running a php file in a form of my own html file. I want the print out at the end the key values in my arrays. The arrays are to hold the values of the drop down boxes and radio boxes. I want to know how to connect the values the user chooses inside the ending echo lines for `operating system`, `processor`, `memory` and so forth.

I tried doing:

```
echo "<strong>Operating system:</strong> .$OS. <br>\n";
```

I also tried starting doing a:

```
foreach($OS as $cost => name)
```

but only know about printing inside the loop.
So I am hoping to get help understanding how to do this.

The form is what you see below.
[image]

Below is my `html` code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Computer Store</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type='text/css'>
    select {
      border: 1px solid #669;
      font: bold 14pt;
      color: #3399cc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .c1 {
      width: 150px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #036;
    }
    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
    input[type=text] {
      border: 2px solid #036;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .outerbox {
      border: 2px solid #036;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #ctr {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class='container'>    

  <h2>Online Computer Order Form</h2>

  <form name="OrderForm" method="GET" action="assignment1.php">
    <div class='row outerbox'>
      <h2>Configure your system</h2>
      <table class='table'>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Operating System</td>
          <td>
            <select name="os" id="os">
              <option value="0">--select operating system--</option>
              <option value="w7">Windows 7</option>
              <option value="w7p">Windows 7 Pro</option>
              <option value="w8">Windows 8.1</option>
              <option value="u12">Ubuntu 12.04</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Processor</td>
          <td>
            <select name="processor" id="processor">
              <option selected="selected" value="0">Intel Core i3</option>
              <option value="200">Intel Core i5</option>
              <option value="350">Intel Core i7</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Memory</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="memory" id="memory1" value="2200">128 GB
            <input type="radio" name="memory" id="memory2" value="1600">64 GB
            <input type="radio" name="memory" id="memory3" value="500">32 GB
            <input type="radio" name="memory" id="memory4" value="295">16 GB
            <input type="radio" name="memory" id="memory5" value="0" checked="checked">8 GB

          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Hard Drive</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="hd" id="hd1" value="0" checked>320GB
            <input type="radio" name="hd" id="hd2" value="100">500GB
            <input type="radio" name="hd" id="hd3" value="200">1000GB
            <input type="radio" name="hd" id="hd2" value="350">2000GB
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>CD/DVD Driver</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="cdr" id="cdr1" value="0" checked class="d_drive">DVD-ROM Drive
            <input type="radio" name="cdr" id="cdr2" value="50" class="d_drive">DVD+/-RW Drive
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class='row outerbox'>
      <h2>Contact Information</h2>
      <table class='table'>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>First Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="First" size="20" id='first' placeholder="First name">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Last Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Last" size="20" id='last' placeholder="Last name">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='c1'>Phone #</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Phone" size="20" id='phone' placeholder="Phone">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h3>Special instructions/Comments:</h3>
    <textarea name='comments' placeholder="If you have any comments or special instructions, please enter them here" class='form-control' rows='3'>
    </textarea>
    <p id='ctr'>
      <input type="submit" value="Finalize sale" class='btn btn-primary'>&nbsp;
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class='btn btn-danger'>
    </p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

`PHP` file:

```
<?php

// Begin by making variables for the user's First, Last Name and Phone number
$first = $_GET['First'];
$last = $_GET['Last'];
$phone = $_GET['Phone'];
//Array Variables for each section
$OS = array('w7' => 'Windows 7', 'w7p' => 'Windows 7 Pro', 'w8' => 'Windows 8.1', 'u12' => 'Ubuntu 12.04');
$Proc = array('0' => 'Intel Core i3', '200' => 'Intel Core i5', '350' => 'Intel Core i7');
$Memory = array('2200' => '320 GB', '1600' => '64 GB', '500' => '32 GB', '295' => '16 GB', '0' => 
    '8 GB');
$H_Drive = array('0' => '320 GB', '100' => '500 GB', '200' => '1000 GB', '350' => '2000 GB');
$C_Drive = array('0' => 'DVD-ROM Drive', '50' => 'DVD+/-RW Drive');

$Comments = $_GET['comments'];

//Connecting options
foreach ($OS as $cost => $name){


}


//Totaling Cost
$total = 0;
$salesTax = $total * .05;
$purchaseTotal = $total + $salesTax;


//Print out information

echo "Thank you" .$first. " " .$last. " for using Sam's online store.  <br>\n";
echo "You have selected the following system: <br>\n";

echo "<strong>Base system</strong><br>\n";
echo "<strong>Operating system:</strong><br>\n";
echo "<strong>Processor:</strong> <br>\n";
echo "<strong>Memory:</strong> <br>\n";
echo "<strong>Hard drive:</strong> <br>\n";
echo "<strong>DVD Drive:</strong> <br>\n";
echo "<strong>Total:</strong>"  .$total. "<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Sales tax(5%):</strong>"  .$salesTax. "<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Total Amount:</strong>"  .$purchaseTotal. "<br>\n";

echo "<strong>Comments or special instructors:</strong> <br>\n" .$Comments."<br>\n";

?>
```

Comment: in loop `echo "<option value ='".$cost."'>".$name."</option>";`

Comment: This loops all the values for OS values in a line where what I am trying to do is grab what option the user has and print its value at the end after the comment "//Print out Information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grab the values in the same manner as the names**

```
$osValue = $_GET['os'];
$procValue = $_GET['processor'];
$memoryValue = $_GET['memory'];
$hdValue = $_GET['hd'];
$cdrValue = $_GET['cdr'];
```

**and use this as your key to call from the associative array**

```
echo $OS[$osValue];
echo $Proc[$procValue];
echo $Memory[$memoryValue];
echo $H_Drive[$hdValue];
echo $C_Drive[$cdrValue];
```

**Your assignment1.php file, view comments - tested, works.**

```
<?php

/*pulling in variables from get.*/
$osValue = $_GET['os'];
$procValue = $_GET['processor'];
$memoryValue = $_GET['memory'];
$hdValue = $_GET['hd'];
$cdrValue = $_GET['cdr'];
$first = $_GET['First'];
$last = $_GET['Last'];
$phone = $_GET['Phone'];

//Array Variables for each section
$OS = array('w7' => 'Windows 7', 'w7p' => 'Windows 7 Pro', 'w8' => 'Windows 8.1', 'u12' => 'Ubuntu 12.04');
$Proc = array('0' => 'Intel Core i3', '200' => 'Intel Core i5', '350' => 'Intel Core i7');
$Memory = array('2200' => '320 GB', '1600' => '64 GB', '500' => '32 GB', '295' => '16 GB', '0' =>
    '8 GB');
$H_Drive = array('0' => '320 GB', '100' => '500 GB', '200' => '1000 GB', '350' => '2000 GB');
$C_Drive = array('0' => 'DVD-ROM Drive', '50' => 'DVD+/-RW Drive');

$Comments = $_GET['comments'];

//Connecting options
foreach ($OS as $cost => $name){
//stuff you wanna do
}


//Totaling Cost
$total = 0;
$salesTax = $total * .05;
$purchaseTotal = $total + $salesTax;

//Print out information
/* ucwords(string) capitalizes the first letter */
echo "Thank you " .ucwords($first). " " .ucwords($last). " for using Sam's online store.  <br>\n";
echo "You have selected the following options: <br>\n";
/* your values would go here */
echo "<strong>Operating system:</strong> $OS[$osValue]<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Processor:</strong> $Proc[$procValue]<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Memory:</strong> $Memory[$memoryValue]<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Hard drive:</strong> $H_Drive[$hdValue]<br>\n";
echo "<strong>DVD Drive:</strong> $C_Drive[$cdrValue]<br>\n";

echo "<strong>Total:</strong>"  .$total. "<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Sales tax(5%):</strong>"  .$salesTax. "<br>\n";
echo "<strong>Total Amount:</strong>"  .$purchaseTotal. "<br>\n";

echo "<strong>Comments or special instructors:</strong> <br>\n" .$Comments."<br>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for explaining and showing the process for this. I ran using this format and only the First and Last name print out. The rest are empty. Not sure why the values for each printout are empty.

Comment: try hard coding values temporarily (the values variables), see if that shows up, if you see it echo out, then your problem lies in getting the form values over.

ex: $osValues = "w7p";

Comment: So the values work on printing out the "name" like Windows 7 Pro and so forth but doesn't show the connection to printing out the cost value though (Which involves my connection to the total value). I tried adding to the foreach a new variable that equaled the $cost but still no luck . I guess I will keep trying to figure that out.

Comment: where is your cost coming from? is it the value set in the fields? If so, you can just grab it using the $value variables I set. (ex: $hdValue would = 0, 100, 200 or 350) the value would change depending on which option was chosen

Comment: I post my answer to show how I ended up fixing my total values. The values are in fact the 0 100 200 and 350.

Answer (score 0):

What @Conceptz showed above fixed my issues for all but the total information(which involves the key values).

I thought I needed a foreach to get the total values but all i really had to do was this:

```
$base = 890;
$total = $base + $procValue + $memoryValue + $hdValue + $cdrValue;
```

This gives me my $key values for my total.